# Show the longest path to a product in Magento breadcrumbs

Tags: php, magento

My case is the following:

- I display products from my 'Recommended' category on the home page.
- The recommended products are also included in different categories and subcategories.
- I've found a popular solution to display the full path to a product in breadcrumbs. I added the following code to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php:

```
$current_category   = Mage::registry('current_category');
$current_product    = Mage::registry('current_product');
if(!$current_category && $current_product){
    $categories = $current_product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->setPageSize(1);
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        Mage::unregister('current_category');
        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
    }
}
```

- As a result, I see the full path in breadcrumbs on a product page:
  Home > Recommended > Product Name

But I want to show the full path to a product including its "actual" category, not Recommended. How can I force not to show the Recommended category in breadcrumbs, but show, for example, "the longest way" to a product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say you still get the recommended category out of this solution because the recommended category is actually the first one in the list of the category in which this or those product(s) appear.

That say, you can actually exclude some results out of a collection, using `addAttributeToFilter`.

```
$current_category   = Mage::registry('current_category');
$current_product    = Mage::registry('current_product');
if(!$current_category && $current_product){
    $categories = $current_product->getCategoryCollection()
                                  ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                                  ->addAttributeToFilter(
                                      'entity_id',
                                      array( 'neq' => $current_category->getId() )
                                  )
                                  ->setPageSize(1);
    /**
     * so we just get the id of the current category (the recommended category)
     * and we exclude it out of the category collection via "neq", for "not equal"
     **/

    /* You don't really need this foreach, setPageSize(1) actually means : 
       add "limit 1" to my sql query

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        Mage::unregister('current_category');
        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
    } */

    Mage::unregister('current_category');
    Mage::register('current_category', $categories->getFirstItem());
}
```